# Loop through keys if value is greater than 2

Tags: python, performance, dictionary

I have a Python dictionary which has a large (~1.5 million) number of keys. The value associated with each key is a number and I only want to report on values that have values greater than two.

My current code looks something like:

```
ks_ignored = 0
for k in d.keys():
    if( d[k] > 2 ):
        print "Key(%s) has value %s"%( k, d[k] )
    else: 
        ks_ignored += 1
```

My final report shows that about 1.4 million keys were ignored and this takes a very long time to run (about 6 hours). Is there a simple way to loop through all keys which have a value greater than 2 without having to perform the check inside of the loop that will substantially speed this up?

Comment: do you just want a new dictionary with only key values >2? I believe if you want to count ignored values, one way or another you will have to iterate over the original number of values

Comment: Good candidate for `filter`

Answer (score 3):

Use dictionary comprehension to get the valid key values:

```
valid_kv = {k:v for k,v in d.iteritems() if v > 2}
```

Ignored keys:

```
ks_ignored = len(d) - len(valid_kv)
```

Comment: Note that `iteritems` is Python 2. `items` for Python 3. `items` works for Python 2, as well.

Answer (score 1):

If what you want is to loop over the result, [`itertools.ifilter()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.ifilter) should work for you. The following is time execution of [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions), [`filter()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#filter) and [`itertools.ifilter()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.ifilter):

```
import time
import itertools


l = [i for i in range(1000000)]

t1 = time.time()
r1 = [i for i in l if i > 100]
t2 = time.time()

t3 = time.time()
r2 = filter(lambda i: i>100, l)
t4 = time.time()


t5 = time.time()
r3 = itertools.ifilter(lambda i: i>100, l)
t6 = time.time()

print t2-t1
print t4-t3
print t6-t5
```

**Output:**

```
0.151000022888  # lc
0.100000143051  # filter
0.000999927520752  # ifilter
```

**Your solution:**

```
res = itertools.ifilter(lambda item: d[item]>2, d)
```

If getting the number of items that do not satisfy your condition is a requirement, you can use [`filter()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#filter) like below:

```
res = filter(lambda item: d[item]>2, d)
ks_ignored = len(d) - len(res)
```

Or:

```
ks_ignored = len(filter(lambda item: d[item]<=2, d))
```